# simple perl addition program going wrong?

Tags: perl

Hi i am a novice perl learner this simple perl program

```
$inputline= <STDIN>;
print "first input";
print( $inputline); 
$inputline=<STDIN>;
print "second input";
print($inputline);
$sum= $inputline+$inputline;
print"sum 1stinput and 2ndinput";
print($sum);
```

output

```
perl count.pl
3
4
first input3
second input4
sum 1stinput and 2ndinput : 8
```

why is the output 8 instead of being 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you add `$inputline` to itself when it is `4`.

If you want to sum the two inputs, you either have to do it with two variables, or do the addition before the variable changes. E.g.:

```
my $input1 = <>;
my $input2 = <>;
my $sum = $input1 + $input2;
print "Sum: $sum";
```

Or

```
my $input = <>;
my $sum = $input;
$input = <>;
$sum += $input;
print "Sum: $sum";
```

You could do something simpler, such as:

```
perl -nlwe '$sum += $_; print "Sum: $sum";'
```

Which is basically the equivalent of:

```
use strict;
use warnings; # always use these

my $sum;
while (<>) {  # your input
    $sum += $_;
    print "Sum: $sum\n";
}
```

Use Ctrl-C or Ctrl-D to break out of the loop (Ctrl-Z in windows).

Comment: The one-liner is a bit over the top for the novice, don't you think? But nice post!

Comment: @simbabque Well, it's not that complicated. =P Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the variable $intputline twice. The second time you refer to it, it overwrites the previous value. You need to use unique variable names for each variable:

```
$inputline1= <STDIN>;
print "first input";
print( $inputline1); 
$inputline2=<STDIN>;
print "second input";
print($inputline2);
$sum= $inputline1+$inputline2;
print"sum 1stinput and 2ndinput";
print($sum);
```

Answer (score 4):

How can Perl (or anyone else) distinguish $inputline from $inputline? Choose a different name for the second variable.

Answer (score 1):

Always and without fail include the following pragmas at the top of your scripts:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Use lexically-scoped variables ("my"):

```
my $inputline= <STDIN>;
print "first input";
print( $inputline); 
my $inputline=<STDIN>;
...
```

Running this would raise the following exception:

```
"my" variable $inputline masks earlier declaration in same scope at ...
```

Using these pragmas and "my" can help you to avoid this and many other potentially problematic areas in your scripts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i use V5.8.8. upon include use strict and use warnings, it gives me error
Global symbol "$inputline" requires explicit package name at count.pl line 4.

Comment: @user1792060 That's because with strict, you need to declare your variables. The real name of your variable is `$main::inputline`, where `main` is the explicit package name. Usually, lexical variables are used instead, which are declared with `my`. E.g. `my $inputline`.

Comment: @learningperl If you felt that your question has been answered, you should choose an answer and mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark beside it.